# Is there an AutoHotkey REPL?

Tags: autohotkey, read-eval-print-loop

I know that you can run and live-reload `ahk` scripts. And I've seen the [scintilla-based editor](http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/) that provides debugging. But, is there any kind of command-line-based [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)?

I was testing the statement to [get the active window's process name](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm) and thought it would really helpful!

```
ahk> WinGet, active, ProcessName, A
powershell.exe
```

Comment: I really like using a REPL with various languages, but AutoHotKey presents certain challenges. Your example raises a big question: how should the REPL itself be handled? Presumably it would be active when you hit enter, so you'd get the process name of the REPL, not powershell.exe.

Comment: We could probably create a really simple REPL with AHK by presenting a text-entry GUI, creating a temp.ahk file for execution, and wrapping the code in the temp.ahk file with something so that we can pass back a return value. We could kill or hide the text-entry GUI during execution to keep it out of the way.

Comment: Looks like this might be the best there is: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/3152-execute-ahk-code-dynamically/?p=273246

Comment: @Dane, would you summarize that post in an answer and maybe copy/paste the code from the forum into a [gist](http://gist.github.com)? I'd be inclined to upvote and award you the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This may also be something like what you're looking for

[image]

[Forum Topic link](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5714&p=34478&hilit=REPL#p34104)

[GitHub link](https://github.com/joedf/Exo-CLI.ahk)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I open my AHK script NotePad (or Vim, or whatever). Then I add my test code as the first line. I have a hotkey defined to reload the script.

```
  MsgBox, Hello World

  ^+r::
  Reload
  Return
```

So I edit, then Ctrl-s, then Ctrl-Shift-R, test code runs. Works pretty well.